# how to add functions to my function.php using a child theme?

Tags: php, css, child-theme, html

I am trying to add functions to my child theme function.php file but each time i try the site crashes. I dont know how to add the functions the right way.

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

        $parent_style = 'PRANAYAMA_YOGA_THEME_VERSION'; // 

        wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
            array( $parent_style ),
            wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
        );
    }
```

I was using this link [https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/][1], and pasted this code inside my function.php file.

```
// Custom Function to Include
function my_favicon_link() {
    echo <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />' . "\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_favicon_link' );
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site crashes, because you have a typo in that code. You're missing an apostrophe at the beginning of the string:

```
// Custom Function to Include
function my_favicon_link() {
    echo <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />' . "\n";
         ^ missing apostrophe
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_favicon_link' );
```

Here's the fixed version:

```
// Custom Function to Include
function my_favicon_link() {
    echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />' . "\n";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_favicon_link' );
```